# accesing static class static member from another namespace generates: no such reference error

Tags: java, android, class, static

I am writting a specialistic control that involves an own widget-system (...because I must - I am working with raster graphics, so I decided to not use the standard buttons).

I encountered a problem with accessing a static member of a static sub-class that isn't in the name space that I call it from. By what I think - this reference should work without problems, as the static class, and static method both have the public qualifier.

The code is somehow like this:

```
//SpecializedView.java
public class SpecializedView extends View
{
  ...
  button.controler_group[] controler_group;
  button button1;
  public void init()
  {
    button_group=button.controler_group.generate_group(8);//generates the error message
    button1=new button(controler_group); 
  }
  ...
}

//button.java
public class button extends button_specialization
{
  ...
  //EDIT[
  controler_group[]controler_group;
  //]

  public button(controler_group[]controler_group)
  {
    this.controler_group=controler_group;
    ...
  }
  static public class controler_group
  {
    static public controler_group[] generate_group(int size){...}
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I have another project with similar structure and it works well (involving calling the static sub-class static member), it only doesn't involve interaction with the class-object itself (it's a pure static function that works as a namespace-library function). I thought the case may be generation of the array, but the result was identical with any sort of returned value.

Comment: Be more specific about the error message you get. Show the code that doesn't work ;together with the errors. And:read about java coding guides, you are violating them all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be more precise with the members of the classes. The error you specified mean that  you have no member of this name, or that it's by some means unaccesible. As the member you are trying to access (and by the suggestion made in your code).

There is a chance that the compiler understands that you are trying to access a static member of the parent class, that is probably an instance of the class with the same name as the class definition.

Comment: Maybe you are right. I will check it later and post the result. The class has a private meber that is named like the static class. Anyway it's tricky, as the problem has resolution (accesing the static class), an shouldn't be threated as error.